# React native image component not switching between local image and uri when props change

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I have an avatar component and inside it it has the following XML

```
    <Image
      source={avatars && avatars[deferredKey]
        ? { uri: avatars[deferredKey] } : defaultAvatar}
      style={{
        width: size, height: size, borderRadius: size / 2, ...containerStyle,
      }}
      onError={this.onError}
    />
```

When the app loads avatars is null so defaultAvatar loads, then a few seconds later the image receives new props and it should switch to the the uri image but it fails to do that.

When I change the code to

```
   <Image
      source={{ uri: avatars[deferredKey] }}
      style={{
        width: size, height: size, borderRadius: size / 2, ...containerStyle,
      }}
      onError={this.onError}
    />
```

Then the component works as expected with originally the avatar loads blank and a few seconds later it loads the uri image correctly.

The issue seems to only exist when the avatar has to switch from a locally stored asset to a uri.

Comment: Is there a state update after avatars is updated ?

Comment: no im logging avatars[deferredKey] and it runs exactly twice, once as null and once as the correct route.  

Notably with either version of the code if i refresh the component it works correctly, the issue is only on first load

Answer (score 0):

like usual i fought with this for 2 days and then figured out the answer straight after posting.

I edited the code to just use the prop defaultSource and it works as expected now

```
    <Image
      source={{ uri: avatars[deferredKey] }}
      style={{
        width: size, height: size, borderRadius: size / 2, ...containerStyle,
      }}
      defaultSource={defaultAvatar}
    />
```

Comment: this actually isnt the right solution as it puts an image while the avatar is loading as well as when its unsuccessful which is not what i want so im not going to mark it correct if someone can find a way for the toggle one to work it would be much better

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9195. It seems that it is essentially a react-native Image bug and has been for some time.

According to the [spec](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/ImageSource.js#L67) you should be able to do something like this

```
<Image source={{uri : myImage, cache: 'reload'}} />
```

But even that doesn't work.

Turns out the best solution that's been working since 2016 is to essentially add a key to your Image component that points to the source value from state:

```
key={this.state.source.uri}
```